# Nodejs docx-merger plugin "Word found unreadable content"

Tags: javascript, node.js, merge, docx

I'm trying to merge docx files via `docx-merger` library. Everything is good, except of Microsoft Word's `"Word found unreadable content in output.docx. Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If you trust the source of this document, click Yes."` message. It opens the document when click to yes, but not the output file, just a buffer.

Here is my code:

```
const docxMerger = require('docx-merger');
fs.readdir('input/', (err, bufferFiles) => {
    var bufferFilesArr = [];
    bufferFiles.forEach(bufferFile => {
    var file = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('app/temps/buffer',bufferFile), 'binary');
    bufferFilesArr.push(file);
    });
    var mergedDocx = new docxMerger({}, bufferFilesArr);

    mergedDocx.save('nodebuffer', function(data){{
    fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve('output','output.docx'), data, 'utf8',function(err){
        //callback
    });
    }});
});
```

I'm trying here to merge `docx` files which are in the `input` folder.

It merges all of them, but I can not open file without this message.

Answer (score 0):

Header & footer sections is the cause for this issue. Try removing the header and footer sections in the documents.