# How can I merge multiple docx files in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to merge multiple docx files in Nodejs. I've tried `docx-merger` module but takes error which I asked in [Nodejs docx-merger plugin "Word found unreadable content"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58040848/284199)

I've tried `docx-builder`, but it has not only the error like `docx-merger`, but also it combines the pages with shifts.

Is there any good solution about that? I can use any command line exe application, if exists.